# xcode sample project "CurrentAddress": where does current location come from?

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am using Xcode version 4.5.1 and OS X version 10.8.2.

I downloaded the CurrentAddress sample project (ver 1.2) and when I run it the first time it prompts "'CurAddress' Would you like to use your current location", to which I say OK.  I cannot figure out from where the code is getting the location that it ends up using, which is in or near San Francisco, lat 37.7858, long -122.406.  I have looked all over the project and cannot see where these values are coming from.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this comes from CLLocationManager, which either will get that data from the GPS sensor in your iphone device, or from the GPS simulation built in in iPhone Simulator.
San Francisco is the default GPS simulation track, near Apples Headquarter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in simulator, go to simulator debug menu -> Location -> you can set any location here. If I am correct, your  CLLocationManager should pick the current location in simulator from here. In device, it should pick the current location, if the same is enabled.

Comment: Okay I see that now.  Thanks.